# How to use PolyUtil.containsLocation method from Google Maps API Utility Library in titanium android using hyper loop

Tags: titanium, appcelerator-hyperloop

I am using Google Maps API Utility Library in titanium android using hyper loop.But PloyUtil.containsLocation method showing error while passing parameters. How can we pass parameter.

Comment: Please show code that causes the error and preferably also link/show native code how it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you can/want to use the normal ti.map module: checkout this PR https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/ti.map/pull/261.

It adds `containsLocation`:
https://github.com/hansemannn/ti.map/commit/db1582ae44e3bb2ab86e354a2b9b45c794906c85#diff-629cb4ae53387d93242309699182cd16R161

So you don't need to use Hyperloop for this at all

Comment: For ios , i can't find containsCoordinate method in ti.map module.

Comment: it is mentioned in the description of the PR and I see it in the iOS source but I'm not using it so you have to wait till it is merged and tested

Comment: is there any other way , we can check that user is inside or outside polygon geofence in titanium ios..because algorithm are not giving correct result.

Comment: you could just use one of the JS checks like https://github.com/mikolalysenko/robust-point-in-polygon or https://github.com/substack/point-in-polygon